# non www to www not working for wordpress in EC2 instance using safari

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, bitnami, no-www

If I use my safari browser, I cannot get to my website example.com. I have to use www.example.com for it to work. I tried editing htaccess numerous times and still, it doesn't work.My website is using bitami wordpress image (https://docs.bitnami.com/)which is hosted in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here:

By default, we disable .htaccess files due to security and performance reasons. We also move `.htaccess` files content to a file called `htaccess.conf` in the folder /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf. You can check more about it at https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/lamp/administration/use-htaccess/.

If you want to enable .htaccess usage, you would need to set it to `AllowOverride All` in `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All <---- HERE
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3 >
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>
```

And restart Apache after applying your changes.

For more info, find WordPress documentation below:
https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/

Regards